# Enhancing Help option in my android application

Tags: android

I need to add help menu  in my android application to help users know about the app for first time when they start [Should  show pop up screen like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tys2r.png)  
well, I can do this by adding such images but Is there any library or sample project available that I can use to achieve this!
[here is developers link down there is a semi transparent image](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/help.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What needs to happen is getting the locations of the relevant views and pass them, in an intent, to a help activity with a transparent background.  Luckily, there is an open source library for this.  Check out [ShowcaseView](https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView) .  It is what you are looking for.